# Problemas de privilegios error ora-01031

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hola buenas tengo un problema el cual no puedo solucionar queria crear estos synonymos en sql developer

```
    create public synonym SYN_CONTRATO
    for contrato;
```

el cual me dio error de privilegios luego alguien me dijo que hiciera esto para solucionarlo

```
    grant create any sequence to usuario;
    grant create any synonym to usuario;
    grant create any rule to usuario;
```

y ps me dio el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna sugerencia? de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Como lo marca el mensaje el usuario con el que intentas asignar privilegios no tiene esos privilegios, la única manera de poder asignarlos es usar la cuenta del administrador u otra cuenta que cuente con esos privilegios, puedes checar tus privilegios mediante la siguiente consulta:

```
select * from user_sys_privs;
```

Comment: yaya en este caso estoy con el usuario system, tu dices que intente en este caso con el usuario sys?

Comment: Debes usar tu cuenta de administrador, si la cuenta sys es tu cuenta de administrador entonces si, y ya con esta podras asignarle privilegios al usuario system

Comment: y existe alguna forma de saber cual es mi cuenta admnistrador? que eso yo no lo se

Comment: La cuenta de administrador tiene todos los privilegios de la base de datos, ejecutaste la Query que te pase? que resultados te dio?